# Basic Image Viewer with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, width, getelementbyid

I am new with JavaScript and I am trying to learn by coding. I want to make a basic image viewer with a "next" and a "previous" that you can click to move forwards and back through a gallery of ten pictures. So I have my html, my css and my javaScript files and 10 random pictures to try it out.
The files are pretty straight forward:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="firstColumn">
            <p>PHOTOGRAPHY</p>
            <div class="firstColumnSub">
                <p class="photo">SOME TITLE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <p><a href="index.html">BACK</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="controllers">
                <div class="buttons" id="previous">
                    <p onclick="change(-1);">PREVIOUS</p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons" id="next">
                    <p onclick="change(1);">NEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img height="100%" id="front" src="Image1.jpg"></div>
            <div>
                <p id="footer">Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Just a few divs with the image in the center and a previous and a next clickable tags. This is what it loos like:

[image]

The JavaScript file contains a function that loads the different pitures and -and this is my problem- centers them in the middle of the page by grabbing their width and updating the css:

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function setUp() {
    var b = document.getElementById("front").width;
    document.getElementById("container").style.width = b + "px"
}

var imageCount = 1;

function change(x) {
    imageCount = imageCount + x;
    var image = document.getElementById('front');
    var str1 = "Image";
    var str2 = imageCount;
    var str3 = ".jpg"
    var sum = str1.concat(str2, str3);
    image.src = sum;
    var a = document.getElementById("front").width;
    document.getElementById("container").style.width = a + "px"
}
```

I an not posting the css unless required, but you get the idea.

As you press "next" or "previous", you are supposed to get this result:

[image]

[image]

etc... but instead I get all sort of random displays:

[image]

[image]

And here is the thing that is puzzling me: if you keep clicking "back" and "next", the same pictures appear OK the second time round, so it is working but not immediately. Any help appreciated!
Thanks, P.

Comment: Whats the exact problem? Width of images

Comment: yes, if you look at the first three pictures, they are centered and the "previous" and "next" tags are aligned with the corners (because "container" is the div that contains all these elements), but if you look at the last two pictures, "next" and "previous" are randomly positioned. As I said, the problem goes away if you keep going back and forwards.

Comment: So, the images are meant to have different widths, i just want them centered regardless of the width

Comment: Try without changing the width of container i.e. remove `document.getElementById("container").style.width = a + "px"` statement

Comment: If I do that, the pictures all start at the same point, aligned with the tag "previous" which is static as is "next" and the pictures are not centered which is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a CSS positioning issue. The following CSS may do the job for you. If you need further help, then I suggest that you reconsider posting your CSS to get help.

```
 #container #front
 {
    position: relative;
    /* width: 0px;  */ /* set via JS for each element in this use case */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

[Here is a popular Q & A on this subject which contains a lot of resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div/16144913).